# How can I specify a parameter for a contructor which is used by model binding in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

**Model Binding** creates a new object which it maps the form fields to. It usually **requires** an **empty contructor** for this object. However what if you wished to pass a parameter to the ctor for it to say retrieve a record for the object.

I have a feeling that one needs to write a custom model builder which I am reluctant to do.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Roll up your sleeves I guess. You said it yourself: [custom model binder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx).

Comment: Do you have any IoC Containers installed in your project?

Comment: No I do not yet......

Comment: How do they fit into the picture?

Comment: Since I am a relevant beginner to MVC, I have postponed IOC as one of those advanced topics which I should learn, but not now !!! I guess I will use Unity when I get there. Would IOC be the answer to my dilemma? Some examples would be wonderful. At present I am using a cheat which is to use a session variable within the constructor which works great in providing the Id, but it is a cheat.